# Creating Unix Commands with Xcode

Tags: xcode, unix, terminal

I'm trying to make a Terminal Unix command with XCode, and I'm having a little trouble...

What I've been doing is creating a "Standard Tool" written in C in XCode, then copying the produced executable to Developer/Tools/.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Post the error messages, or details of the problems you're having.

Comment: Whenever I try to run my command...

(for example, if the name of the file is "crbot")

I type "crbot" in the Terminal, and hit enter, and it says:

-bash: crCmd: command not found

Comment: Does it work if you run with the full path?  In terminal type `/Developer/Tools/crbot` (or whatever the full path to the executable is).

Comment: Yes it does... but is it possible to make that into a command?

For example, typing "crbot" into the Terminal and hitting enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add /Developer/Tools to your PATH environment variable.  In your .profile (or IIRC .bash_profile), you need something like:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/Developer/Tools"
export PATH
```

Comment: when I type ${PATH} and hit return, /Developer/Tools/ shows up... doesn't that mean it's already added?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but what exactly does it say?  (Maybe the path is misformatted somehow.)  Let's go back to the error message.  You said: "I type "crbot" in the Terminal, and hit enter, and it says: -bash: crCmd: command not found".  If the command crbot is not found it should say `-bash: crbot: command not found`.  So where did crCmd come from?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped- it did say:
 -bash: crbot: command not found.

It's odd, because I'm able to run it by typing "/Developer/Tools/crbot", but it doesn't work when I just type "crbot".